# Extract and Save a value from a 3rd party numberpicker widget

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am using codejeff.com numberpicker for my android app. I would like to extract the value set by the user and save it so that the value persists even if the app is force stopped. Could someone help me on how I can utilize Shared preferences to save the value.. I have gone through a lot of examples but none of them has resolved my issue. Any code snippet will be highly appreciated.
My code snippet is:

```
<net.technologichron.android.control.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/numberPicker4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker4" >
</net.technologichron.android.control.NumberPicker>.
```

So now I need to extract the value from the numberpicker and make it persist.
My java file is as follows:

public class splashscreen extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void reset(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, splashscreen.class);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   finish();
   overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}
}
 Please tell me what all lines of code I need to add to save and restore one value from number picker everytime the app is force stopped. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify what you need help with: extracting the number from the numberpicker? (If so, please post what code you do have.) Or are you asking about how to generally persist information from you app even after it is closed?

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24743588/edit) rather than adding new information to comments.

Comment: My basic question is: If I am to save the value in one of these numberpicker, what are the pieces of code I need to add to my java file? I have tried matching a lot of examples and general snippets but none of them have served the purpose. So I am hoping you can give me a specific piece of code.